# Showing a subset of polynomials in $P_n$ is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Show that the set of all polynomials in $P_n$ that have a horizontal tangent at $x=  0$ is a subspace of $P_n$. Find a basis for this subspace.

The way i approached this question was to get a polynomial that had x as a denominator and prove that the set holds for addition and scaling implying the subspace, but finding a basis for this space eludes me.

Comment: You cannot have "polynomials" with $x$ in a denominator; this would be some sort of rational function (ratio of two polynomials), but not a polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for every $p(x) \in P_n$, $p(x)$ has a horizontal tangent at $x=0$ iff $p'(0) = 0$.

Let $S = \{ p(x) \in P_n \mid p'(0) = 0 \}$. We show that $S$ is a subspace of $P_n$:

- Let $p(x)$ be the zero polynomial: $p(x) = 0$. Then $p'(x) = 0$, so $p'(0) = 0$. Thus, $0 \in S$.
- Let $p(x)$, $q(x) \in S$. Then $p'(0) = 0$ and $q'(0) = 0$. Then $(p+q)'(x) = p'(x) + q'(x)$, so $(p+q)'(0) = p'(0) + q'(0) = 0 + 0 = 0$. Thus, $p(x) + q(x) \in S$.
- Let $p(x) \in S$, and let $c$ be a scalar. Then $p'(0) = 0$. Then $(cp)'(x) = cp'(x)$, so $(cp)'(0) = cp'(0) = c0 = 0$. Thus, $cp(x) \in S$.

Thus, $S$ contains $0$ and is closed under both vector addition and scalar multiplication. Therefore, $S$ is a subspace of $P_n$.

Now to the question about a basis for $S$.

- Let $p(x) \in S$. Then $p(x) = c_0 + c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + \cdots + c_n x^n$ for some scalars $c_0$, $c_1$, $c_2$, $\ldots$, $c_n$. Then $p'(x) = c_1 + 2 c_2 x + \ldots + n c_n x^{n-1}$, so
  $$
  0 = p'(0) = c_1.
  $$
  Therefore, $p(x) = c_0 + c_2 x^2 + \ldots + c_n x^n$, i.e., the coefficient of $x$ in $p(x)$ is $0$. Since $p(x)$ was arbitrary, we have shown that every element of $S$ can be written as a linear combination of elements of $\{1, x^2, x^3, \ldots, x^n \}$, i.e., we have shown that $\{ 1, x^2, x^3, \ldots, x^n \}$ spans $S$.
- Moreover, $\{1,x^2, x^3, \ldots, x^n \}$ is linearly independent, since it is a subset of the basis $\{1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^n \}$ for $P_n$.

Therefore, $\{ 1, x^2, x^3, \ldots, x^n \}$ is a basis for $S$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* The map $p \mapsto p'(0)$ is a linear transformation $P_n \to \mathbb R$. The set is the kernel of this map.